# Waving line in css

Tags: css, animation, css-transitions

I need to do a wavy line animation in css.

I would like it to look something like this:

[image: wavy line]

My code:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="line"></div>
</div>

.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  background: #fff;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

.line {
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: url('http://tiny .pl/gjhxv') left top repeat-x;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/agxx3ysk/

Comment: What have you tried? We won't do everything for you...

Comment: I'm looking for tips on how to get started. How can I change the line shape?

Comment: Asking for tutorial or book recommendations is off-topic on stackoverflow. Try google

Comment: https://greensock.com/forums/topic/11376-creating-animated-wavy-lines/

Answer (score 2):

Check this answer already on StackOverflow
[Link to the wave](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21825476/5633939)

[one more link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44665993/waves-in-css-or-svg)

Just change `fill:none` and `stroke:red` properties. and you could further play around with this.